# Is there a way to start a Twilio phone conference via an api call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conference

I played around a lot now and still can't figure out if there is a way of starting a conference via the API.

What do I want to achieve:
I would like to set up a conference, keep all participants still listening to music and than start that conference on a button press.

After reading the documentation about the conference API, I saw you can update the conference object status:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-resource?code-sample=code-update-a-conference-to-end-it&code-language=Ruby&code-sdk-version=5.x

The update to end the conference works fine (the example):

```rb
conference = @client.conferences('CFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                    .update(status: 'completed')
```

But as soon as I try to use `.update(status: 'in-progress')` to start the conference i get:

```
in-progress is not a valid choice
https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20001
```

The documentation sounds like you are able to do it:

> The new status of the resource. Can be: Can be: init, in-progress, or completed. Specifying completed will end the conference and hang up all participants

Do I miss something?

Yes there are more than 2 calls connected, both of them with 'startConferenceOnEnter' set to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can use the [REST API to generate a call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls) to [your client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls?code-sample=code-make-an-outbound-call-to-a-twilio-client&code-language=php&code-sdk-version=5.x).

The URL you pass to this call should point to an endpoint on your server that will return the TwiML to start the conference:

```xml
<Response>
  <Dial><Conference>{insert Conference room name}</Conference></Dial>
<Response>
```

During this request where you return the conference call TwiML, you can also [kick off a new request to start a call to the phone number you want to dial using Twilio's REST API as mentioned here using curl](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls?code-sample=code-make-an-outbound-call-to-a-twilio-client&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=5.x).

Alternatively, you could maybe [do it with Twilio Studio like this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-conference-call-line-twilio-studio).

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: Not quite sure if i understand that correct, but it means there is no way to start a conference via the API, right? And need to start the conference via a dummy call, something like:

`call = @client.calls.create( url: 'http://myserver.com/redirect/callToConference', to: 'client:SomthingRandomNotImportant', from: 'client:SomthingRandomNotImportant' )`